# Member "validPurchase" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract super

Tags: solidity, contract-development

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract MinInvest {

    function validPurchase() internal returns (bool) {
    bool moreThanMinimalInvestment = msg.value >= 0.1 ether; // change the value to whatever you need
    return super.validPurchase() && moreThanMinimalInvestment;
    }
}
```

> browser/Untitled.sol:7:12: TypeError: Member "validPurchase" not found
>   or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract super
>   MinInvest
>       return super.validPurchase() && moreThanMinimalInvestment;

How do i add validPurchace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you missed the inheritance of your contract.

When using `super.method()` you are actually calling to already existing method in one of the contracts you've inherited from.

So, you just need to specify inheritance by `contract MinInvest is <some-contract> {`, where `<some-contract>` has method `validPurchase()`.